# Node npm - referencing three.js module on the front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, three.js

I'm currently using the node npm to manage dependencies like jquery on the front end. Using the following method.

**Server (working)**

```
app.use('/jquery', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/jquery/dist/'));
```

**Client (working)**

```
<script src="/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
```

This works, but I was hoping to be able to manage the dependency 'three.js' from the server side too. Something like...

**Server (not working)**

```
app.use('/three', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/three/dist/'));
```

**Client (not working)**

```
<script src="/three/three.js"></script>
```

**Error ()**

*failed to load resource the server responded with a status of 404 (not found)*

How can I find the directory structure of the npm module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the three.js project, the built files are located in the `build` directory, not the `dist`.

On the server, this should work:

```
app.use('/three', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/three/build/'));
```